# Optimum way to validate DataTable for duplicate or invalid fields in a specific column with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, optimization

I am trying to find the best way to determine if a `DataTable`

1. Contains duplicate data in a specific column

**or**

2. If the fields within said column are not found in an external `Dictionary<string, string>` *and* the resulting value matches a string literal.

This is what I've come up with:

```
List<string> dtSKUsColumn = _dataTable.Select()
                                      .Select(x => x.Field<string("skuColumn"))
                                      .ToList();

bool hasError = dtSKUsColumn.Distinct().Count() != dtSKUsColumn.Count() ||
    !_dataTable.AsEnumerable()
               .All(r => allSkuTypes
                   .Any(s => s.Value == "normalSKU" && 
                             s.Key == r.Field<string>("skuColumn")));
```

`allSkuTypes` is a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the key is the SKU itself, and the value is the SKU type.

I cannot just operate on a 'distinct' `_dataTable`, because there is a column that must contain identical fields (Said column cannot be removed and inferred, since I need to preserve the state of _dataTable).

---

### So my question:

Am I handling this in the best possible way, or is there a simpler and faster method?

### UPDATE:

The DataTable is not obtained via an SQL query, rather it is generated by a set of rules from an spreadsheet or csv. I have to make do with only the `allSKuTypes` and `_dataTable` objects as my only 'outside information.'

Comment: If you are using EF db first then the fastest way is to write a function in sql and map it with [EdmFunction].

Comment: @Nathan, I updated my question because it implied that _dataTable is obtained via a SQL query or the like. Also I have to treat it as if _dataTable and allSkuTypes are all I have access to and are immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is not optimal.

Let `N = _dataTable.Rows.Count` and `M = allSkuTypes.Count`. Your algorithm has O(2 * N) space complexity (the memory allocated by `ToList` and `Disctinct` calls) and O(N * M) time complexity (due to linear search in the `allSkuTypes` for each `_dataTable` record).

Here is IMO the optimal solution. It uses single pass over the `_dataTable` records, a `HashSet<string>` for detecting the duplicates and `TryGetValue` method of the `Dictionary` for checking the second rule, thus ending up with O(N) space and time complexity:

```
var dtSkus = new HashSet<string>();
bool hasError = false;
foreach (var row in _dataTable.AsEnumerable())
{
    var sku = row.Field<string>("skuColumn");
    string type;
    if (!dtSkus.Add(sku) || !allSkuTypes.TryGetValue(sku, out type) || type != "normalSKU")
    {
        hasError = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The additional benefit is that you have the row with the broken rule and the code can easily be modified to take different actions depending of the which rule is broken, collect/count only the first or all invalid records etc.

Comment: +1 I was hoping to find a solution that with minimal side effects, but I guess in so doing I'm locking myself into the unnecessary complexity of a 'stateless' validation.